# MSCRM: How to use odata and web api to look for records having a given value in any one of multiple fields?

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

Example: I look for all accounts where phone number is 555 555 555, and I want to look in telephone1, telephone2 and telephone3. Is that feasible with odata?

On [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248(v=nav.90).aspx), they say the following about the logical or:

> You can use OR operators to apply different filters on the same field. However, you cannot use OR operators to apply filters on two different fields.

Given that limitation, I really don't know how to do that filter.

Comment: You can try to filter `telephone1 eq '555' or telephone1 eq '' and telephone2 eq '555'`... and so on.

Comment: I had thought of that, but then I will receive also the accounts without a phone number, which is not desired in my case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

First thing: The link you are referring is for NAV not for CRM.

It's totally [possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461(v=crm.7).aspx#Anchor_1) to do `OR` filter with two different attributes using OData endpoint:

```
/AccountSet?$filter=AccountCategoryCode/Value eq 2 or AccountRatingCode/Value eq 1
```

In your case:

```
/AccountSet?$filter=telephone1 eq '555 555 5555' or telephone2 eq '555 555 5555' and telephone3 eq '555 555 5555'
```

Comment: Thanks! I had actually seen it was NAV but had assumed it applied to CRM since my tests were unsuccesful... However I'll give it another try today and let you know.